# How can I create the lbpcascade_frontalface.xml about OpenCV in Android Studio 2.0

Tags: opencv3.0, android-studio-2.0

I use the OpenCV Example named "openCVSamplefacedetection".
There is a xml file "lbpcascade_frontalface.xml"
How can I create this file by myself ?
thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I found

\opencv\build\x64\vc12\bin\

opencv_createsamples.exe

opencv_traincascade.exe

but is there the shared, stronger, face frontal LBP file to download ?

thanks a lot.